# Debugging iMX6 bare-metal with Segger JLink

Tags: j-link

I'm attempting to debug a bare-metal application on iMX6UL with Segger JLink Pro.  I seem to be able to connect and download the application properly:

```
$ JLinkExe -Device mcimx6g2
SEGGER J-Link Commander V6.30k (Compiled Apr  9 2018 18:33:16)
DLL version V6.30k, compiled Apr  9 2018 18:33:07

Connecting to J-Link via USB...O.K.
Firmware: J-Link V10 compiled Mar 29 2018 17:45:34
Hardware version: V10.10
S/N: 600101813
License(s): RDI, FlashBP, FlashDL, JFlash, GDB
VTref = 3.319V


Type "connect" to establish a target connection, '?' for help
J-Link>connect
Please specify target interface:
  J) JTAG (Default)
  S) SWD
TIF>
Device position in JTAG chain (IRPre,DRPre) <Default>: -1,-1 => Auto-detect
JTAGConf>
Specify target interface speed [kHz]. <Default>: 4000 kHz
Speed>1000
Device "MCIMX6G2" selected.


Connecting to target via JTAG
J-Link script: Setting up AP map
TotalIRLen = ?, IRPrint = 0x..000000000000000000000000
J-Link script: Setting up AP map
TotalIRLen = 13, IRPrint = 0x0101

**************************
WARNING: At least one of the connected devices is not JTAG compliant (IEEE Std 1149.1, 7.1.1.d, IR-cells). (NumDevices = 3, NumBitsSet = 2)

**************************

JTAG chain detection found 3 devices:
 #0 Id: 0x5BA00477, IRLen: 04, CoreSight JTAG-DP
 #1 Id: 0x00000001, IRLen: 05, Unknown device
 #2 Id: 0x1891D01D, IRLen: 04, JTAG-DP
AP map detection skipped. Manually configured AP map found.
AP[0]: AHB-AP (IDR: Not set)
AP[1]: APB-AP (IDR: Not set)
Using preconfigured AP[1] as APB-AP
AP[1]: APB-AP found
ROMTbl[0][0]: CompAddr: 80001000 CID: B105900D, PID:04-001BB961 TMC
ROMTbl[0][1]: CompAddr: 80002000 CID: B105900D, PID:04-004BB906 CTI
ROMTbl[0][2]: CompAddr: 80003000 CID: B105900D, PID:04-004BB912 TPIU
ROMTbl[0][3]: CompAddr: 80004000 CID: B105F00D, PID:04-001BB101 TSG
ROMTbl[0][4]: CompAddr: 80020000 CID: B105100D, PID:04-000BB4A7 ROM Table
ROMTbl[1][0]: CompAddr: 80030000 CID: B105900D, PID:04-005BBC07 Cortex-A7
Found Cortex-A7 r0p5
6 code breakpoints, 4 data breakpoints
Debug architecture ARMv7.1
Data endian: little
Main ID register: 0x410FC075
I-Cache L1: 32 KB, 512 Sets, 32 Bytes/Line, 2-Way
D-Cache L1: 32 KB, 128 Sets, 64 Bytes/Line, 4-Way
Unified-Cache L2: 128 KB, 256 Sets, 64 Bytes/Line, 8-Way
System control register:
  Instruction endian: little
  Level-1 instruction cache enabled
  Level-1 data cache disabled
  MMU disabled
  Branch prediction enabled
Cortex-A7 identified.
J-Link>halt
PC: (R15) = 00008588, CPSR = 400001F3 (SVC mode, THUMB FIQ dis. IRQ dis.)
Current:
    R0 =00000000, R1 =00900A30, R2 =10000000, R3 =00000800
    R4 =00000000, R5 =00000002, R6 =00900BC4, R7 =02020000
    R8 =0000858C, R9 =0000858C, R10=021E8000, R11=0001C200, R12=000100A1
    R13=00000000, R14=020E0014, SPSR=0091FF64
USR: R8 =021E8000, R9 =0001C200, R10=000100A1, R11=00000000, R12=020E0014
    R13=74EBFF3F, R14=88CF1BAA
FIQ: R8 =D5414CD5, R9 =C2C0BE88, R10=BF81059E, R11=B1E909E0, R12=B59B17CF
    R13=E0D763BF, R14=4945FC6E, SPSR=3F0ADED2
IRQ: R13=D68B397E, R14=1DBD7DCF, SPSR=670467EF
SVC: R13=0091FF64, R14=00002F4B, SPSR=000001D3
ABT: R13=DA163F5A, R14=79EBF7E5, SPSR=C50E1756
UND: R13=F0F71639, R14=618DCCFE, SPSR=C907A3EA
J-Link>SetPC 907000
J-Link>loadbin "test.bin" 907000
Halting CPU for downloading file.
Downloading file [test.bin]...
O.K.
J-Link>verifybin "test.bin" 907000
Loading binary file test.bin
Reading 66348 bytes data from target memory @ 0x00907000.
Verify successful.
```

I performed some spot checks at memory offsets (0x00, 0x100, 0x200, etc) and it matches the binary file.  However, when I attempt to run the application, the processor jumps outside the application memory and does not run properly:

```
J-Link>mem32 907000, 2
00907000 = E59FF018 E59FF018 
J-Link>mem32 907100, 2
00907100 = EE40AF10 F57FF06F 
J-Link>mem32 907200, 2
00907200 = E3800040 EE010F30 
J-Link>halt
PC: (R15) = 00907000, CPSR = 400001F3 (SVC mode, THUMB FIQ dis. IRQ dis.)
Current:
     R0 =00000000, R1 =00900A30, R2 =10000000, R3 =00000800
     R4 =00000000, R5 =00000002, R6 =00900BC4, R7 =02020000
     R8 =0000858C, R9 =0000858C, R10=021E8000, R11=0001C200, R12=000100A1
     R13=00000000, R14=020E0014, SPSR=0091FF64
USR: R8 =021E8000, R9 =0001C200, R10=000100A1, R11=00000000, R12=020E0014
     R13=74EBFF3F, R14=88CF1BAA
FIQ: R8 =D5414CD5, R9 =C2C0BE88, R10=BF81059E, R11=B1E909E0, R12=B59B17CF
     R13=E0D763BF, R14=4945FC6E, SPSR=3F0ADED2
IRQ: R13=D68B397E, R14=1DBD7DCF, SPSR=670467EF
SVC: R13=0091FF64, R14=00002F4B, SPSR=000001D3
ABT: R13=DA163F5A, R14=79EBF7E5, SPSR=C50E1756
UND: R13=F0F71639, R14=618DCCFE, SPSR=C907A3EA
J-Link>s
J-Link>s
00000004:  1C F0 9F E5        LDR     PC, [PC, #+0x1C]    ; 0x00000028
J-Link>halt
PC: (R15) = 0091FFBC, CPSR = 400001DB (UNDEF mode, ARM FIQ dis. IRQ dis.)
Current:
     R0 =00000000, R1 =00900A30, R2 =10000000, R3 =00000800
     R4 =00000000, R5 =00000002, R6 =00900BC4, R7 =02020000
     R8 =00000040, R9 =00000040, R10=021E8000, R11=0001C200, R12=000100A1
     R13=00000000, R14=020E0014, SPSR=F0F71639
USR: R8 =021E8000, R9 =0001C200, R10=000100A1, R11=00000000, R12=020E0014
     R13=74EBFF3F, R14=88CF1BAA
FIQ: R8 =D5414CD5, R9 =C2C0BE88, R10=BF81059E, R11=B1E909E0, R12=B59B17CF
     R13=E0D763BF, R14=4945FC6E, SPSR=3F0ADED2
IRQ: R13=D68B397E, R14=1DBD7DCF, SPSR=670467EF
SVC: R13=0091FF64, R14=00002F4B, SPSR=000001D3
ABT: R13=DA163F5A, R14=79EBF7E5, SPSR=C50E1756
UND: R13=F0F71639, R14=00907002, SPSR=400001F3
J-Link>s
0091FFBC:  1C F0 9F E5        LDR     PC, [PC, #+0x1C]    ; 0x0091FFE0
J-Link>s
00011050:  20 11 9F E5        LDR     R1, [PC, #+0x120]   ; 0x00011178
J-Link>halt
PC: (R15) = 00011054, CPSR = 400001DB (UNDEF mode, ARM FIQ dis. IRQ dis.)
Current:
     R0 =00000000, R1 =020DC2AC, R2 =10000000, R3 =00000800
     R4 =00000000, R5 =00000002, R6 =00900BC4, R7 =02020000
     R8 =00000040, R9 =00000040, R10=021E8000, R11=0001C200, R12=000100A1
     R13=00000000, R14=020E0014, SPSR=F0F71639
USR: R8 =021E8000, R9 =0001C200, R10=000100A1, R11=00000000, R12=020E0014
     R13=74EBFF3F, R14=88CF1BAA
FIQ: R8 =D5414CD5, R9 =C2C0BE88, R10=BF81059E, R11=B1E909E0, R12=B59B17CF
     R13=E0D763BF, R14=4945FC6E, SPSR=3F0ADED2
IRQ: R13=D68B397E, R14=1DBD7DCF, SPSR=670467EF
SVC: R13=0091FF64, R14=00002F4B, SPSR=000001D3
ABT: R13=DA163F5A, R14=79EBF7E5, SPSR=C50E1756
UND: R13=F0F71639, R14=00907002, SPSR=400001F3
J-Link>s
00011054:  00 10 91 E5        LDR     R1, [R1]
J-Link>s
00011058:  00 00 51 E3        CMP     R1, #0x00
J-Link>s
0001105C:  02 00 00 1A        BNE     #+0x08              ; 0x0001106C
J-Link>
```

Can anyone recommend additional debugging steps?  Other than checking that the application was downloaded OK and PC set properly, I'm not sure how to determine what is happening here.

EDIT: The following figure shows Ozone debugger after target connection is initialized:
[image: Ozone screenshot]
When I single step, it jumps to a seemingly random address and then my binary does not execute properly if I hit "Resume program execution".  Perhaps that's related to the BLX instruction shown above?

Comment: Is this really a jlink question?  If it's not about the jlink but rather about debugging your program, the title needs to be changed.  See if the backtrace "bt" command will show anything.  Or put a breakpoint at the start address.   Are you sure you linked your code for the correct address, and wrote it to the correct address?

Comment: Try Ozone debugger from SEGGER - it will probably give you more information than the command line application.

Comment: @ChrisStratton  I'm not sure if the issue lies in my usage of JLinkExe (likely), improper linking, or the JLink pod/hardware.  Sometimes the exact sequence I showed above works successfully.  Most of the time, it does not.  That leads me to believe I've got the application linked and loaded properly, since it works sometimes.

Comment: In Ozone: open the ELF file compiled with debug symbols ( -g option for gcc). You will see much more, perhaps the startup code.

Comment: This probably has little to do with the JTAG adapter, more likely you have built your program improperly, or asked the debug adapter to load it at the wrong address.  What happened when you tried putting a breakpoint at the start address defined in the chip's programmer's manual???

Comment: The application is the "DDR Stress Test" provided by NXP.  Per NXP's instructions, it is to be loaded to address 0x907000 (OCRAM).  The .bin file is from the U-boot ZIP that NXP provides.

When I created the post, I had never seen JTAG loading work.  With more attempts (as stated above), it does succeed sometimes, probably 10% of the time.  I wish I knew what was causing the inconsistent behavior.  Soon I hope to use this tool to verify custom boards where DDR may or may not actually work, and I'd rather not be fighting JTAG problems then.  (Right now I'm just running it on an EVK)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that the executable (DDR Stress Test) is compiled with ARM instructions.  The iMX6UL comes up with Thumb enabled by default (CPSR = 0x1F3).

If I set CPSR = 0xD3 (disable Thumb, enable ARM), then the application works.

I think the "variation in behavior" I experienced was due to not completely resetting the board (power cycle) every time.  I would see different results if u-boot or Linux had been executed.

Comment: Normally ARM vs. Thumb state is set by bit 0 of the target address of a branch instruction.  If this were intended to run from non-volatile storage on boot it would have to be compatible with the hardware startup mode.  Otherwise, it's the responsibility of the caller to set the LSB of the target address correctly when branching to invoke it, from which the hardware will set the mode bit.  But if you're invoking it by setting the PC with a debugger, then you have to set the mode bit of the CPSR yourself, as it's the *target LSB in the act of branching* and not LSB of PC which controls.